# Pesquisa em array, com várias relações chave x valor

Tags: php

### Cenário exemplo

Tenho o seguinte *Array*:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'A' => 'X',
    'B' => 'Y',
    'C' => 1,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'A' => 'X',
    'B' => 'Y',
    'C' => 2,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'A' => 'X',
    'B' => 'W',
    'C' => 1,
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'A' => 'X',
    'B' => 'W',
    'C' => 3,
  ),
)
```

---

### Objetivo

Gostaria de pesquisar, se o *array* `permissoes` contém um *array*, que atenda o 3 valores específicos, por exemplo:

```
A = X
B = Y
C = 2
# Encontrará o array [1]

A = X
B = Y
C = 3
# Não encontrará nenhum valor
```

---

### Dúvida

- Qual a melhor forma para buscar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

É só você construir um *array* semelhante ao que está na lista de permissões e utilizar a função `array_search`:

```
$A = 'X';
$B = 'Y';
$C = 2;

$indice = array_search(compact('A', 'B', 'C'), $permissoes);
```

A função `compact` irá gerar um *array* `['A' => 'X', 'B' => 'Y', 'C' => 2]`, buscando por esse *array* na lista de permissões. Se encontrar, é retornado o índice da primeira ocorrência; caso contrário será retornado `false`.

```
$A = 'X';
$B = 'Y';
$C = 2;

if (($indice = array_search(compact('A', 'B', 'C'), $permissoes)) !== false) {
    echo "Permissões encontradas no índice {$indice}";
} else {
    echo "Permissões não encontradas";
}
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/PrettyAwesomeBookmarks) | [Ideone](https://ideone.com/3MJKrw)</sup>

Answer (score 5):

Você pode usar a função [`array_search`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) para buscar os valores dentro do array. Mas se você não precisa saber em que posição está o elemento, a função [`in_array`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) serve ao propósito.

O comportamento de [comparações entre arrays](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php) vai depender se a comparação é estrita ou não. Onde a comparação normal checa se os arrays tem os mesmos pares chaves/valores e a comparação restrita também checa se estão na mesma ordem. Ex.:

```
$a = ['a' => 1, 'b' => 2];
$b = ['b' => 2, 'a' => 1];

$a == $b;  // true
$a === $b; // false
```

Dito isso, é só usar o `in_array`:

```
<?php

$permissoes = [
    ["A" => "X", "B" => "Y", "C" => 1],
    ["A" => "X", "B" => "Y", "C" => 2],
    ["A" => "X", "B" => "W", "C" => 1],
    ["A" => "X", "B" => "W", "C" => 3],
];

$existente = ["A" => "X", "B" => "Y", "C" => 2];
$inexistente = ["A" => "X", "B" => "Y", "C" => 3];

// Printa: "Tem permissão"
if (in_array($existente, $permissoes)) {
    echo "Tem permissão";
} else {
    echo "Não tem permissão";
}

// Printa: "Não tem permissão"
if (in_array($inexistente, $permissoes)) {
    echo "Tem permissão";
} else {
    echo "Não tem permissão";
}
```

<sup>[Repl.it](https://repl.it/@fernandosavio/SOPt-348424-6333) com o código funcionando</sup>

É importante lembrar que o método `array_search` retorna o índice do elemento encontrado no array ou `false` caso o elemento não seja encontrado. Então lembre de fazer uma comparação restrita, pois se o elemento estiver na primeira posição o resultado será zero, que é um valor *falsy* (se você usar `in_array` isso não é um problema). Ex:

```
<?php

$a = [1, 2, 3, 4];

$result = array_search(1, $a);

// Printa: "Não encontrado"
if ($result) {
    echo "Encontrado";
} else {
    echo "Não encontrado";
}
```

Comment: Cara, agradeço a resposta, muito boa, mas o que me facilitou a vida, foi o `compact()` como na resposta do Woss. +1 de qualquer forma! ✌️